# Invalid client credential while getting access token from paypal ios sdk

Tags: ios, authentication, paypal

I am creating an app in which I have to use `paypal` payment, after successful payment I have to generate payment detail, so I need access token.

I get the method how to get access token, I tried in hurl. It and I successfully get that access token using Client ID and Client Secret. Till this there is no problem.

But when I put those credentials (Client_ID and Client_Secret) in my code it always returns with invalid client credential.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"];
// NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
// cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
// timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

NSString *client_id = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
NSString *client_secret = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", client_id, client_secret];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];

[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"en_US" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"client_credentials",@"grant_type", nil];

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Below is the log I prints in `didFinishLoading`

```
2015-07-14 14:54:25.130 paypalNativeDemo[1478:61010] {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

Comment: You should NEVER include the `client_secret` in an app that is being distributed to untrusted parties. A malicious user could decompile the app, recover the secret and make any API call they'd like on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Sandbox credentials are different than live. Make sure you're using your sandbox `client_id` if you are talking to sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error is due to the REST app not yet being approved. I would suggest contacting PayPal Support through the number in your account and advise the agent that you are calling to check the status of your REST app.

Comment: if there is app approval problem then why it give me success response in web version, means i call that API from http://www.hurl.it with my app credential. But it gives this error in iOS app only.